How to import global variables in webpack or rollup project
I want to create a module for CMS using Rollup or webpack.
I have a script tag that contains a few variables which I need to use in my webpack module, but I can't include them directly because these render on the server-side.
I tried to use the globals section in the rollup config, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.
The tag script with the variables:


<script>
  var dle_root       = '/';
  var dle_admin      = '';
  var dle_login_hash = '{HASH}';
  var dle_group      = 5;
  var dle_skin       = 'testskin';
  var dle_wysiwyg    = '2';
  var quick_wysiwyg  = '2';
  var dle_min_search = '3';
</script>



How to define external variables in Rollup or webpack?
How to do it correct?

You can use module export plugins to achieve what you are looking for in your webpack.config.js setup a separate new webpack.DefinePlugin() object parameters like below:


const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // add your rest of th other configurations here
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      dle_root: JSON.stringify('/'),
      dle_admin: JSON.stringify(''),
      dle_login_hash: JSON.stringify('{HASH}'),
      dle_group: JSON.stringify(5),
      dle_skin: JSON.stringify('testskin'),
      dle_wysiwyg: JSON.stringify('2'),
      quick_wysiwyg: JSON.stringify('2'),
      dle_min_search: JSON.stringify('3')
    })
  ]
};



Access them like below:


console.log(dle_root); // Outputs:'/'
console.log(dle_admin); // Outputs:''
console.log(dle_login_hash); // Outputs:'{HASH}'
console.log(dle_group); // Outputs:5
console.log(dle_skin); // Outputs:testskin




I can't move these variable into webpack config their values dynamicly updates by php

You have not mentioned anything about that in the question. Then consider putting it all in asset file so that it can be available globally

I wrote I can't include them directly because these render on the server-side.
